# .bat transcription in .sh

Tags: sql, shell, batch-file

today I launch a .bat script under Windows that launches SQL procedures. I would like today to be able to launch these same procedures but from a Linux server. Here is my .bat and my SQL file, do you have any idea how I can do that?

```
    Set Fichier=orders


TYPE C:\Loader\Exe\Blanc.txt >>C:\Loader\Mail\Loader.LOG
ECHO Alimentation de la table products  >>c:\Loader\Mail\Loader.LOG

sqlplus bbc/info@xe @C:\Loader\RunProc\%Fichier%.SQL

REM Detection du fichier erreur du RUNPROC
if not EXIST c:\loader\bad\%Fichier%.err goto FIN

REM usage: mailsend [options]
REM Where the options are:
REM    -d     domain*      - domain name for SMTP Helo
REM    -smtp  hostname/IP* - of the SMTP server
REM    -p     SMTP port    - SMTP port
REM    -t     to,to..*     - email address/es of the reciepient/s
REM    -c     cc,cc..      - Carbon copy address/es
REM    -b     bcc,bcc..    - Blind carbon copy address/es
REM    -f     address*     - email address of the sender
REM    -sub   subject      - subject
REM    -l     file         - a file containing the email addresses
REM    -a     file         - attach this file
REM    -y     mime type    - MIME type for the attached file
REM    -m     file         - include this text file
REM    -v                  - verbose mode
REM    -V                  - show version info
REM    -help               - shows this help

C:\loader\exe\mailsend.exe -d email.fr -smtp smtp.email.fr -t email@email.fr -f email@email.com -sub "Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'intégration" -m C:\loader\bad\%Fichier%.err

:FIN
```

My SQL file

```
    Point Sql



whenever sqlerror exit failure;
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
EXECUTE proc_commande_clts_detail7;
EXECUTE proc_commande_clts_detail6;
EXECUTE proc_commande_clts;
EXECUTE proc_bilan ('COMMANDE_CLTS');
EXECUTE proc_commande_clts2;
EXECUTE proc_bilan ('COMMANDE_CLTS (SUPPR)');
EXECUTE proc_commande_clts_detail;
EXECUTE proc_bilan ('COMMANDE_CLTS_DETAIL');
EXECUTE proc_commande_clts_detail8;
EXECUTE proc_bilan ('COMMANDE_CLTS_DETAIL (PACK)');
EXECUTE proc_commande_clts_detail2;
EXECUTE proc_bilan ('COMMANDE_CLTS_DETAIL (SUPPR)');
EXECUTE proc_commande_clts_detail3;
EXECUTE proc_bilan ('COMMANDE_CLTS_DETAIL (PR ACHAT)');
EXECUTE proc_commande_clts_detail9;
EXECUTE proc_bilan ('COMMANDE_CLTS (EXPE)');
EXECUTE proc_clients;
EXECUTE proc_bilan ('CLIENTS')
EXIT;
```

Thanks you

Comment: You're just running a sqlplus command (which exists in Linux) and running an executable that is also compatible with Linux. What part or porting the script to bash are you having trouble with? There's practically nothing to change.

Comment: It's at the syntax level or I do not know. Do you know what I need to change? Thanks

Comment: Have you even tried anything? Once you change `REM` to `#`, only `type` and the `if` statement need to be changed.

Comment: It is using smtp to send mail as well. Have you configured it in your linux environment? One thing i can tell you is `sqlplus` commands won't change if it is linux or Windows. For other two commands above it ,you can simply google to find the equivalent commands in Linux.

Comment: Okay, I'll do like that. Thanks for your help